# How do I access general eclipse preferences in my own plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I want to get value of general console properties in my plugin.
How can I do that?

I think I should do something like this:

```
IPreferenceStore store = ScriptUIActivator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
store.getDefaultInt(preferenceName);
```

But what is "preferenseName"? And which one preference store do I have to use.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqSuE.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These preferences are in the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` plugin

You can access the preference store using

```
IPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "org.eclipse.debug.ui");
```

The preference values are listed in the `IDebugPreferenceConstants` interface, but this is a internal class so should not be used.

The values are

```
public static final String CONSOLE_SYS_ERR_COLOR= "org.eclipse.debug.ui.errorColor";
public static final String CONSOLE_SYS_OUT_COLOR= "org.eclipse.debug.ui.outColor"; 
public static final String CONSOLE_SYS_IN_COLOR= "org.eclipse.debug.ui.inColor"; 
public static final String CONSOLE_BAKGROUND_COLOR= "org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleBackground";
```

since these values are internal they may be changed without notice.

The preference values are RGB strings, you can use `PreferenceConverter` to deal with these:

```
RGB color = PreferenceConverter.getColor(preferenceStore, key);

PreferenceConverter.setValue(preferenceStore, key, rgb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You access preferences with an ID :

ID from `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.preferences.IDebugPreferenceConstants` :

```
"org.eclipse.debug.ui.errorColor"
"org.eclipse.debug.ui.outColor"
"org.eclipse.debug.ui.inColor"
"org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleBackground"
```